# How to config my.cfg file for mysql which was installed from sources?

Tags: debian, mysql, source

I installed MySQL 5.6 from sources on debian.

MySQL folder is /usr/local/mysql.

Here is several question:
1) I would like to config my.cfg. But I couldn't find several parameters:

```
   socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (file is missing)
   pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (file is missing)
   !includedir    /etc/mysql/conf.d/ (folder is missing)
```

Where are they?

2) I would like to make autostart on reboot system. But earlier I've installed from apt-get install source and had */etc/init.d/mysqld start* and it would run automatically. Now I should run manually */etc/init.d/mysql.server start*.

So, how to run it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed this yourself from source then I think there are some additional steps you need to do to complete your installation.

Specifically the following guides need to be followed:

- [2.18.1. Unix Postinstallation Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/unix-postinstallation.htm)
- [4.4.6. mysql_install_db — Initialize MySQL Data Directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-install-db.html)
- [2.18.1.2. Starting and Stopping MySQL Automatically](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/automatic-start.html)

You might want to also [check out this guide](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mysql5.htm) which shows a lot of the steps specific to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure those paths exist and that they are writable by the mysql user.